# working with traded numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

A man want 762 by a number, but he trade it and its quotient result 13 and its rest was 13. What the quotient and rest of the original number? 
$$ q = ?; r=? $$
$$ 762 = q \cdot \overline{ ab } + r $$
$$ 762 = 13 \cdot \overline {ba} + 21 $$

Another way to write this is:
$$ \frac{762-r}{ \overline{ba}}=r $$
$$ \frac{762-21}{ \overline{ba}}=13 $$

Comment: Should it be $ 762 = 13 \cdot \overline {ba} + 13?$ That matches your text better.

Comment: No, 21 is the rest of 762 / ba. That means the ba is greater than 21

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct reading if the rest was $21$ instead of $13$ as in the text.  Your set off equations essentially divide twice by the number.

Comment: Sorry my notation was wrong a should write $ 762 = 13 \cdot \overline{ba} + 21 $

Comment: Another way to write it is $ \frac{762 - 21}{ \overline{ba}}= 13 $

Comment: You still haven't correct the rest in the first line, but everything else is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just solve $762 = 13 \cdot \overline {ba} + 21$ by subtracting $21$ from both sides and dividing by $13$.  This gives $\overline {ba}=57$  Then $\overline {ab}=75$ so divide by that.

Comment: The answer is the $ 762 = 10 \cdot 75 + 12 $

Comment: So quotient = 10 and rest = 12

Comment: Yes, that is correct.